# react native stack navigator change font in nav bar

Tags: react-native, fonts, stack-navigator

I'm using a stack navigator to navigate between a few screens in my app. I want to update the name using a prop I send using the prop listName:

```
  this.props.navigation.navigate('List', {  
        JSON_ListView_Clicked_Item: id, listName: name 
    })
```

I also want to set the font as 'lobster' which I have tried below and does not work.

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import LogInForm from '../screens/loginForm';
import ListsView from '../screens/listsView';
import List from '../screens/list';
import Header from '../shared/header';
import React from 'react';
import { DrawerRouter } from 'react-navigation-drawer';

const screens = {
    LogIn: {
        screen: LogInForm,
        navigationOptions: {
            drawerLockMode: 'locked-open',
            headerShown: false,
            
        }
    },
   ListsView: {
       screen: ListsView,
       navigationOptions: 
       ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
            headerLeft: () => null,
          headerTitle: () => <Header title=''  navigation={navigation} />
          
        }
      }
    },

   List: {
     screen: List,
    }  
}

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(screens, {
defaultNavigationOptions: {
    backgroundColor: '#0e99b5',
    height: 60,
    headerTintColor: 'orange',
    fontFamily: 'lobster',
    title: 'test Title'}

});

export default HomeStack;
```

Is it possible to change the font in the stack navigator in this way? If not how can it be achieved? Is there a way utilizing the above I could access the route params?

How could I access the listName prop in the StackNavigator?

I've also been unable to center align the title.